# Can i use a variante as name for create a new table in MYSQLdb?

Tags: python, variables, web-scraping, mysql-python

I have got this html source :

```html
<div id="ceg">
        <span class="cegnev">THE_NAME</span><br>
        <span class="cim">XXX</span><br>
       YYY  </div>
```

I want to use this value : THE_NAME as a variante(or constante, doesnt matter), which one i can define the table name in MYSQL.

```js
query = """ 
   CREATE TABLE 'THE_NAME(as variable)' (
  `X` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Y` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Z` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `U` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `I` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `O` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ID` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8"""
```

How can i make a variable with this part of html code, and how can I reference to this name in my query code? Is it possible? - Python 2.7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this....

```
query = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "+ table_name+ " name VARCHAR(120), date CHAR(22)"
```